# Finding Anonymous Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, object, anonymous

In an HTML file you specify a script named test.js that contains:

```
{ "thing" : 123 };
```

There is no variable name.  That is, you DO NOT have

```
var myObject = { "thing" : 123 };
```

How can you find this object or somehow get a reference or a handle to it since it does not have a variable name?

Comment: If you want a reference of the object, create it as an attribute inside the object itself.

Comment: Do you mean passing that as an anonymous object? What you mean is unclear to me

Comment: Have a look at [google +1 javascript configuration object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523105/google-1-javascript-configuration-object). I think this is the situation you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

> How can you find this object or somehow get a reference or a handle to
>   it since it does not have a variable name?

Well you can't. If you include a javascript file containing this value you will simply get a javascript error (`Invalid label`) so the javascript execution will stop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd load the data with AJAX using test.js as the URL. You can assign it to your own variable there.